# work environment / sound designing in a multi-functional studio space

Tags: home-studio, acoustics

hello,

partly for economic reasons, i'm considering leaving both my apartment and studio, and move into a single 65m2 ex-factory loft which i'd like to use as multi-functional space for living and working. the question arises is how if at all could i utilize a specified area of that space for my day-to-day sound design work? 
... the loft is rather spacious and have a rectangle shape. i'm thinking of bounding one corner of it with two removable walls or partitions of some material (recommendations?) and have my 'studio' set up there (basically a laptop with two Adam A7X monitors). it's important to note that i'm not planning to use this space to perform recordings of any type... it's mostly about sound editing and basic post-pro work. i'm worried whether i'll be able to hear things accurately in such non-ideal acoustic conditions... any experiences with similar situations? any suggestions for things i could do to improve the acoustics of such work environment?

many thanks,
K

Comment: Can you split the room in two with dividers, leaving both partitions rectangular?

Comment: yes i can... but the ceiling is quite high though... like 3 or 3.5 meters.